# Upload image with Alamofire , Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire, image-upload, alamofireimage

For upload image to server I am using Alamofire 4.4 and Swift 3. 
Swager information:

```
curl -X POST "url/id/upload" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@craneB.png;type=image/png"
```

My Swift code:

```
let headers = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer \(GlobalToken.appToken)",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" ]
    let url = BaseUrl+"1f510b93-5177-4880-447d-08d6fe7a9498"+"/upload"
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage, 0.9)

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

        if let data = data{
           multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "name", fileName: "filename", mimeType: "image/png")
        }

    }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: url, method: .post, headers: headers) { (result) in
        switch result{
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
           // upload.validate(statusCode: 200..<299)
            upload.responseJSON{ response in
                print("Succesfully uploaded")


                switch response.result {
                case .success(let JSON):

                case .failure(_):

                }
                if let err = response.error{
                    print(err)
                    return
                }
            }
            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                              })
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")

        }
    }
```

Respons:
Upload Progress: 1.0
Succesfully uploaded .
 But I have error :

> POST BaseUrl/1f510b93-5177-4880-447d-08d6fe7a9498/upload (500) {
>       Message = "Internal Server Error. - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. \n   at
>   MaterialService.UploadAsync(Guid Id, IFormFile file)

I guid Id send in URL, file with multipartFormData. Upload on Sawager is work. TY

Comment: your `BaseURL` is encapsulated by double quotes.

Comment: @koropok wrong on copy to this q

Comment: @IbrahimSušić try uploading pic with postman and see if image gets uploaded successfully or not. if it still gives 500 then there is problem on server side

Comment: @SahilManchanda I' m try upload with postman error it is same.